# nvm: N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed

Tags: node.js, nvm

I have `nvm` setup to use the latest long term support version in `~/.nvm/alias/default`, by setting it to `lts/*`.

When I try and have my shell initialize my nvm version (zsh), I get the following error:

> N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Error: `N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed`

I got this error after doing `nvm use` (switching to older Node version 8.11.1, shown in .nvmrc file), `nvm uninstall` (newer Node version 9.0.0), then a `git push`.

`nvm ls` shows **my "default" Node version was pointing to the uninstalled one**: `default -> 9.0.0 (-> N/A)`. This caused the error.

**To fix:** `nvm alias default node` points "default" to the latest installed Node version (8.11.1).

Now `nvm ls` shows `default -> node (-> v8.11.1)`.

Comment: Sometimes you will have to ran `nvm install lts/*` previously to `nvm alias default node`

Comment: The key part of the command is `nvm alias default` - as long as the version with the keyword after default is installed, you're good to go. Incidentally, I think `stable` is a better "default" than `node`.

Answer (score 34):

Turns out this error is telling me that I don't have it installed (ie the latest long term support version). To fix it, I had to run:

```
$ nvm install 'lts/*'
```

and it worked after that! Snagged from [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1651#issuecomment-357555493)

Answer (score 26):

## Your "default" Node version is not reachable (many reasons)

Many answers but there isn't a straightforward solution, let's try with:

```
nvm install 'lts/*'
nvm alias default node
```

the first command ensure you have latest LTS version installed and then set the default.

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same issue when i used nvm to install node 12 and node 10. To fix this i used the command:
`nvm alias default node`

Answer (score 9):

### Prevent nvm from trying to `use` when first loading

You may not need (or want) the latest version of node installed, and yet wish to have the nvm command available, so in your .bashrc (or equivalent) include the --no-use flag when loading nvm

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use  # This loads nvm
```

Thanks to [Ioannis Poulakas](https://www.ioannispoulakas.com/2020/02/22/how-to-speed-up-shell-load-while-using-nvm/)

Comment: This is a particularly useful answer since this is exactly what NVM's own documentation provides for the `.bashrc`, except it's missing the "--no-use"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed the issue and set the default version to a specific Node LTS version:

```
nvm install lts/gallium # node v16
nvm alias default lts/gallium
```

(**Notes:** the commands in other answers **did not** fix the issue for me

```
nvm install 'lts/*'
nvm alias default node
```

I'm using ZSH & nvm v0.34.0)

Answer (score -4):

I fixed it by running nvm use v12.21.0